# 16.10 broke my Samba

Tags: networking, samba, cifs, smb

I just upgraded from 16.04.1 to 16.10. I think that my Samba is broken. I've got two machines doing almost the exact same thing.

I've checked the `/etc/samba/smb.conf` and it looks like all of my shares from 16.04 are still there.

**testparm** seems to run fine, but does give this error:

```
rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)
WARNING: The "syslog" option is deprecated
```

**smbclient** shows me this:

```
$ smbclient -L //caspurr
WARNING: The "syslog" option is deprecated
Enter password: 
Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 3.0.37]

Sharename       Type      Comment
---------       ----      -------
IPC$            IPC       IPC Service (TomatoUSB)
Video           Disk      video
Public          Disk      public
Pictures        Disk      pictures
Music           Disk      music
Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 3.0.37]

Server               Comment
---------            -------
CASPURR              TomatoUSB
SATELLITE-E55        Satellite-E55 server (Samba, Ubuntu)

Workgroup            Master
---------            -------
WORKGROUP            CASPURR
```

**smbclient** lets me connect to a Public share on my router:

```
$ smbclient //caspurr/Public
WARNING: The "syslog" option is deprecated
Enter password: 
Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 3.0.37]
smb: \> dir
.                                   D        0  Sat Jul 11 20:19:54 2015
..                                  D        0  Sat Jul 11 13:23:13 2015
9-great-freeware-programs.pdf       A   754624  Thu Jan  6 17:08:53 2011

    124665852 blocks of size 1024. 121369992 blocks available
smb: \> exit
```

In **Nautilus** I sometimes see **Windows Network**, sometimes not:

[image]

If I **DO** see Windows Network, and I click on it, I get this, forever:

[image]

**What's wrong with my Samba?**

Lastly, all of the above was done with the firewall turned off. If I turn the firewall on, results are worse. Can anybody tell me what ports I need to open?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to edit /etc/samba/smb.conf and add a wins server address of my router...

```
# WINS Server - Tells the NMBD components of Samba to be a WINS Client
# Note: Samba can be either a WINS Server, or a WINS Client, but NOT both
;   wins server = w.x.y.z
    wins server = 192.168.0.1
```